# Logic app not tracking custom property as guid to log analytics, why?

Tags: logging, guid, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

I'm, currently have using a Compose connector in Logic app to track properties extracted from the trigger, the value is a Guid extracted from an xml string inside a Json object.

But for some reason trying to log a Guid to log analytics dosen't work. But when i just write some random string it loggs the value extracted exactly the same way.

So this is what i'm doing:

In the logic app i've set it up like this:

```
    "Log_Validation_Exception": {
    "inputs": {
        "ErrorInfo": "https://smartportdeviations.blob.core.windows.net@{body('Create_Validation_Exception_Blob')?['Path']}",
        "LoggingCode": "ValidationFaliure",
        "PayloadID": "@{first(xpath(xml(json(decodeBase64(triggerBody()?['ContentData']))['XmlObject']), '//*[name()=\"passId\"]/text()[1]'))}"
    },
    "runAfter": {
        "Create_Validation_Exception_Blob": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "trackedProperties": {
        "ErrorInfo": "@outputs('Log_Validation_Exception')?['ErrorInfo']",
        "LoggingCode": "@outputs('Log_Validation_Exception')?['LoggingCode']",
        "PayloadID": "@outputs('Log_Validation_Exception')?['PayloadID']"
    },
    "type": "Compose"
},
```

when writing a GUID in the passID element as a value:

```
<passId>6725ca5f-83e1-c097-e053-e600000a4f6c</passId>
```

i get nothing in the tracked properties...

but when adding something like this:

```
<passId>adsgfasdgasdasdf</passId>
```

Then it loggs it...

Pictures below for reference.

[image]

In OMS:
[image]

Also i know the logic app successfully extracts the GUID because its there in the logic app run log:

[image]

So what am i missing here?

**UPDATE:**
For some reason if i put a letter behind or infront the GUID, then it loggs the GUID. But if it is an explicit GUID format on the value then it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the tracked property determines its name. The tracked property name follows this pattern:
`trackedProperties_<property name>_<type char>`

So `PayloadID` becomes `trackedProperties_Log_Validation_Exception_PayloadID_g` or `trackedProperties_PayloadID_s` depending on whether the value is a GUID or string.

I'm not sure whether this has anything to do with your issue because I am not sure how you queried for the Tracked Properties.